# 2002 kawasaki zx6r stutters

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, tuning, ninja

My 2002 Kawasaki stutters below 4000 rpm when in neutral while giving it throttle it also does the same thing while in gear but if I raise the rpm just before take off it shoots out the hole with no problem.

I don't think this is normal, what could it be?

Comment: Kawasaki used carburetors on early models and fuel injection on later models. It appears it changed around the early 2000s, so can you tell us which your bike has? When was the last time it was serviced/tuned up? Also, has the bike been sitting for a length of time or ridden frequently?

Comment: It is carb and had been sitting a while I've recently had the carbs cleaned and was told they were pretty well synchronized, ive also changed the fuel filter spark plugs and battery

Comment: That is good to know. Has the fuel in the tank been replaced? Fuel loses its volatility as it ages, and becomes less efficient at burning. If the fuel is what was stored with the bike, you might want to drain it and put fresh in.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen at any throttle setting?

It looks like your 2002 ZX-6R is carbureted, so it could have something to do with your jets. Different components of the carburettor are responsible for different throttle settings. If its actually low throttle settings instead of low engine speeds, I'd try cleaning the carbs and adjusting the settings.

[image]

Otherwise, I'd check the battery voltage. It's possible there is a problem with your charging system, and you aren't getting enough voltage for a good spark until the engine and generator are turning at a higher speed.

Comment: I've recently had the carbs cleaned, changed the fuel filter,  fuel pump, and spark plugs. bought a new battery not even a week ago, at higher speed and revs it seems fine the bike idol's right at 1000 rpm and if i hit the gas hard it struggles until it gets to 4000 rpm and then it opens up and sounds great

Comment: Still, check the battery voltage. If it needed a new battery, that could also indicate a problem with the charging system. Otherwise, it sounds like a fuelling issue to me. If you ride at about 1500rpm in 6th gear, what happens when you go WOT? Is it different from if you gradually roll on the throttle?